# How do I pick then sort MongoDB documents and then find next document to mine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a collection of documents, which I need to first narrow down by set criteria, then sort alphabetically by string value inside those documents — let's say that's a "search result". I then need to find document that matches a given `_id` and then pick a document next to it (before or after) from the above "search result".

#### Background:

I use mongoose to query my database via Node.js.

I have a set of "special sections" in my blog that are comprised of all the articles that must have three particular conditions associated within the keys in the document. I can get the list of articles belonging to said section like so:

```
const specialSectionListQuery = Article.find({
  tag: { $ne: "excluded" },
  [`collections.cameras`]: { $exists: true },
  status: "published",
})
```

To finish creating the "special section," I must sort the documents alphabetically via their `title` attribute:

```
.sort({ [`collections.cameras.as.title`]: "asc" })
```

Now I want to add a link to "next article within the same special section" at the bottom of such articles. I know `_id` and any other value needed from the current article. The above query gives me an ordered list of documents within the section so I can easily find it within that list `specialSectionListQuery.findOne({ _id: "xxx" }).exec()`.

However, I need to find the **next article** within the above list. How do I do that?

#### My attempts thus far:

I tried to create article list via aggregation, which led me nowhere (I simply made my app do exactly the same thing — make a list for a "special sectin"):

```
Article.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      tag: { $ne: "excluded" },
      [`collections.cameras`]: { $exists: true },
      status: "published",
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      [`collections.cameras.as.title`]: 1,
    },
  }
]).exec()
```

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to iterate to the next document in the list properly.

I have thought of saving the list in Node.js memory (variable) and then finding what I need via JavaScript but that can't be scalable.

I have considered creating a new collection and saving the above list there but that would require me to either 1) do it every time a document is altered/added/deleted via Node.js — which is a lot of code and it may break if I interact with database another way 2) rebuild the colleciton every time I run the query, but that feels like it'll lack in performance.

Please help and thank you!

P.S.:
Example collection which should cover most of the cases I'm looking to solve for:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "Canon",
    collections: { cameras: { as: { title: "Half-Frame" } } },
    tag: "included",
    status: "published"
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "Pentax",
    collections: { cameras: { as: { title: "Full-Frame" } } },
    tag: "included",
    status: "published"
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    name: "Kodak",
    collections: { film: { as: { title: "35mm Film" } } },
    tag: "included",
    status: "published"
  },
  {
    _id: 4,
    name: "Ricoh",
    collections: { cameras: { as: { title: "Full-Frame" } } },
    tag: "included",
    status: "published"
  },
  {
    _id: 5,
    name: "Minolta",
    collections: { cameras: { as: { title: "Half-Frame Review" } } },
    tag: "excluded",
    status: "published"
  },
  {
    _id: 4,
    name: "FED",
    collections: { cameras: { as: { title: "Full-Frame" } } },
    tag: "included",
    status: "draft"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is to extend your `$sort` by adding `_id` so that it always returns documents in deterministic order:

```
{
    $sort: {
        "collections.cameras.as.title": 1,
        _id: 1
    }
},
{
    $limit: 1
}
```

Once your first query returns the document with `_id: 2` and `collections.cameras.as.title: Full-Frame`, you can use below query to get subsequent document:

```
{
    $match: {
        $and: [
            {
                tag: { $ne: "excluded" },
                "collections.cameras": { $exists: true },
                status: "published",
            },
            {
                $or: [
                    { 
                        $and: [
                            { "collections.cameras.as.title": {  $eq: "Full-Frame" } },
                            { "_id": { $gt: 2 } }
                        ]
                    },
                    { "collections.cameras.as.title": {  $gt: "Full-Frame" } }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    $sort: {
        "collections.cameras.as.title": 1,
        _id: 1
    }
},
{
    $limit: 1
}
```

In this case due to deterministic `$sort` you can exclude previously found document by adding additional filtering criteria and the order should be preserved.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zmKWLV9U1qx)